# Using Oauth2 Node library in React app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, oauth-2.0, passport.js

currently I have a React app, there I need to authenticate using OAuth2. I have the server, url's,callbacks, and clients already, now the only thing that I need is to exchange the code sent by the OAuth2 server for an access token.

I was reviewing some libraries that are made for javascript to handle these situations, for example:

- [Simple Oauth2](https://github.com/lelylan/simple-oauth2)
- [Passport](http://passportjs.org/)

I was trying with `simple-oauth2` however I see that it's made for node.js applications, and they use `require` to import the libraries. My question is, can I use that kind of libraries on client side using React? if so, which is the correct way to import that library inside my component? because readin their examples they are focus on express/node apps. Am not really a Javascript or node developer so I need help in this.

Comment: Passport is for express framework specifically. Purely client-side OAuth2 clients have to use implicit flow, since no app secrets can be used without exposing them. As a side note, questions to recommend  library are offtopic here.

Comment: @AlexBlex thank you, yes I was afraid also about expose the credentials. so then I will need a backend endpoint to exchange tha token

Comment: Please read https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-1.3.2. I am sure if you google for implicit grant libraries you find some.